# How does bash alias understand "$@"?

Tags: bash, alias, bash-alias

I am trying to write an alias to do 2 things

```
$alias cde='cd "$@" && echo'
```

but for some reason when I call it with

```
$cde test
test
```

all that happens is it echos test:

It looks like my argument is not getting passed to the first statement, and instead is being used up at the end of the whole alias. From my understanding, the `$@` was supposed to consume all arguments so that it never reaches the echo. Any way I can use an argument in the first part, and not the second?

Comment: I wrote a generic answer but there are some parts of your question that are unclear. "Any way I can use an argument in the first part, and not the second?" – do you want just `echo` without arguments? What sense does it make? Why `&&`? **What do you want to happen exactly?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alias does not take arguments. It simply replaces one string with the other in your command line. There's no separate `$@` for an alias so `"$@"` doesn't expand as you expected here. It expands as if you typed directly in your command line (by hand):

```
echo "$@"
```

(This doesn't show the exact word splitting but it's not the point).

However a function does take arguments and has its own `$@`. It's not clear to me if you wanted your `echo` to print your alias "arguments". If so, I would do this instead of an alias:

```
cde() { cd "$@" ; echo "$@" ; }
```

Or rather:

```
cde() { cd "$@" ; pwd ; }
```

The difference is with handling (echoing) multiple arguments, expanding paths like `..` etc. Also `-L` and `-P` options to `pwd` may be useful.

If you would like to override `cd` then you need `command` to avoid infinite loop (the function would call itself otherwise):

```
cd() { command cd "$@" ; pwd ; }
```

Comment: It's actually worse than that. The `"$@"` when the alias is executed is actually whatever the **current** positional params are. Test the alias with `set -- foo bar; cde baz` -> `bash: cd: foo: No such file or directory`